# Combine different results of "group by" queries in the same table

Tags: sql, group-by

I need to make some comparation between 2 years: sales by product, sales by category, etc.
How can I have this in one table having 3 columns:

- first column = product, category, etc
- second column = sales in 2021
- third column = sales in 2022

Sample of queries that must be combined in one single table as the one below

```
select product_code, sum(amount)
from product
where year = '2021'
group by product_code

select product_code, sum(amount)
from product
where year = '2022'
group by product_code
```

---

```
select category_code, sum(amount)
from category
where year = '2021'
group by category_code

select category_code, sum(amount)
from category
where year = '2022'
group by category_code
```

Please, see the final table
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/smF7h.png

**NOTE!**
*If for instance in 2021 there was no "product D", it will be 0  for "Sales_2021" or the "product A" is no longer present in 2022, it will be 0 for "Sales_2022".*

Thank you

Comment: Next time, please tag your SQL request with the DBMS you are using. SQL dialects differ a lot and the correct answer may heavily depend on the DBMS. Then, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your sample data as formatted text into your request instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two things here:

1. Conditional aggregation (a `CASE` expression inside the aggregation function) in order to get 2021 and 2022 in one go.
2. A union of two intermediate result sets (product figures `UNION ALL` category figures).

And as any table - and a query result is again a table - is unordered, we need an `ORDER BY` at last to get products first and categories second and also the products ordered alphabetically and the categories, too.

The complete query:

```
select category_or_product, sales_2021, sales_2022
from
(
  select
    product_code as category_or_product,
    sum(case when year = 2021 then amount else 0 end) as sales_2021,
    sum(case when year = 2021 then amount else 0 end) as sales_2022,
    1 as product_first
  from product
  group by product_code
  union all
  select
    category_code as category_or_product,
    sum(case when year = 2021 then amount else 0 end) as sales_2021,
    sum(case when year = 2021 then amount else 0 end) as sales_2022,
    2 as product_first
  from category
  group by category_code
) unioned
order by product_first, category_or_product;
```